# Multiple Choice App Feature

Tags: ios, ios8, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to create a simple multiple choice quiz feature for an app. I have a pList with all the questions, multiple choice options, and the answer. The questions have a different number of multiple choice options. Most questions have 4 options, but others have 5, 6, or 7. I am unable to change the amount of options in each question. I don't know if I should use Interface Building to build the XIB file or I should create the constraints programmatically for each UILabel and UIButton based on the number of multiple choice options. This app is iPad only and iOS 7 & 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make the answers live in a UITableView and then each answer is just a cell and you can do it all in Interface Builder.

A second option, if you know you'll never have more than 8 answers, is to put all eight UILabels and set unused labels to be hidden.  Then you can do it all in interface builder and just toggle the hidden property in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use UITableView
Question fill in section
Answer options fill in rows of section

In number of section
{

return no of questions

}

In number of rows for section
{

return no of answer for that section(question)

}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  Fill the questions

}


- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

fill the answer 

}
```